# sjPlot interaction plot regression line getting cut off

Tags: r, sjplot

I am trying to create an interaction plot from a multilevel model using sjPlot in RStudio. When I set limits on the y-axis, one of the regression lines is cut off. There are no data points beyond the limits. I am receiving the warning: "Scale for y is already present. Adding another scale for y, which will replace the existing scale."

Thanks for any advice.

The model is as follows:

```
model1b <- lmer(NEGAFF ~ DIST_PC*EVINT_PC + (1 + DIST_PC + EVINT_PC | UUID), data = DATA_POOLED)
```

Below is the code for the plot:

```
plot_model1b_inv <- plot_model(model1b, type = "pred", #can use the same model type as before from sjplot
                                terms = c("EVINT_PC", "DIST_PC 
                                          [-0.24, 0.24]"),
                                title = " ", 
                                axis.title = c("Stressor Intensity", "Momentary Negative Affect"), 
                                legend.title = "Spontaneous Distraction Use",
                                show.data = TRUE, dot.size = 0.6, jitter = 0.2,
                                ci.lvl = 0.95, colors = Dark2) + apatheme + xlim(-1,1) + ylim(0,1) + theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```